# Grails Bootstrap XmlSlurper Service no result

Tags: grails, service

I'm new to Grails and working on my little project. What I have problem with is my XML reading Service - ReadService - has a function `read()` that returns `XmlSlurper()`. Function reads the xml file, as it's write it in console with `println`. But when I try to print the result `XmlSlurper` in Bootstrap, I don't get anything.

```
class BootStrap {
  def ReadService

  def init = { 
     servletContext ->
     def xml = ReadService.read()
     println xml
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have misspelled your service.
Your `ReadService` must be saved in `grails-app/services`.

To use the service you have to declare them like this

```
def readService
```

and within `init` you could use them as follows:

```
def xml = readService.read()
```

As you can see, the first letter must be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see now the problem isn't with reading the xml itself, rather with bootstraping with it, as changing Service name to lovercase helped. I use ReaderService to read xml file with addresses and build address objects. Here is mine Bootstrap code: 
`

```
class BootStrap {
     def readService 

      def init = { 
         servletContext ->
         def xml = readService.read()
         println xml
       def adress = new mobilmed.Adres(ulica:xml.adress.street, dom:xml.adress.house, miejscowość:xml.adress.residance, kodPocztowy:xml.adress.postCode, poczta:xml.adress.post).save()
        if(adres.hasErrors()){
       println adres.errors}
      }
}
```

When I run it, I got classical "no such property" error.

```
| Error 2012-08-28 06:42:36,784 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No such property: adres for class: BootStrap
Message: No such property: adres for class: BootStrap
   Line | Method
->>  10 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   301 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|   294 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|   270 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run                              in     ''
^   662 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Of course, i checked, and Boostraping for defined variables works just fine, like this:

```
def karolzam = new mobilmed.Adres(ulica:"Turkusowa", dom:"8/22", miejscowość:"Lublin", kodPocztowy:"20-572", poczta:"Lublin").save()
        if(karolzam.hasErrors()){
       println karolzam.errors}
```

Looks like the Bootstrap don't "seeing" variables that can print on console. :/